# Upload multiple file in Multiple Path PHP

Tags: javascript, php, list, file, codeigniter

I have a problem with uploading multiple files on one form. In this case I try to upload 6 picture with different path which are differentiate with if-else condition.

The problem is when I tried to upload files, the path where the files uploaded is located in the first path selected on the condition. In example when the first if-else condition direct the path to "upload/gambar_soal/, then the next files will be uploaded there too even though it has the different condition.

Here's the code:

```php
public function edit_soal()
    {
        $message_alert="";

        $this->cek_aktif();
        if ($this->input->post('id_mapel')=="") {
            redirect('adm/m_soal');
        }
        if ($this->input->post('id_mapel')!=0) {
            # code...

        $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
        var_dump($data['id']);
        $data['id_mapel'] = $this->input->post('id_mapel');

        // $file_name = $k . "_" . $__id_soal . "." . $ekstensi[1];


        $data['foto_opsi_a'] = $this->input->post('foto_opsi_a');
        $data['foto_opsi_b'] = $this->input->post('foto_opsi_b');
        $data['foto_opsi_c'] = $this->input->post('foto_opsi_c');
        $data['foto_opsi_d'] = $this->input->post('foto_opsi_d');
        $data['foto_opsi_e'] = $this->input->post('foto_opsi_e');

        $data['opsi_a'] = $this->input->post('opsi_a');
        $data['opsi_b'] = $this->input->post('opsi_b');
        $data['opsi_c'] = $this->input->post('opsi_c');
        $data['opsi_d'] = $this->input->post('opsi_d');
        $data['opsi_e'] = $this->input->post('opsi_e');

        $data['bobot_a'] = $this->input->post('bobot_a');
        $data['bobot_b'] = $this->input->post('bobot_b');
        $data['bobot_c'] = $this->input->post('bobot_c');
        $data['bobot_d'] = $this->input->post('bobot_d');
        $data['bobot_e'] = $this->input->post('bobot_e');

        $data['soal'] = $this->input->post('soal');
        $jenis  = array("gambar_soal","foto_opsi_a", "foto_opsi_b", "foto_opsi_c", "foto_opsi_d", "foto_opsi_e");
        for ($i=0; $i <6 ; $i++) { 

        $jeson = array();
            $status = "";
            $msg = "";

            if ($status != "error") {


                if($jenis[$i]=="gambar_soal"){
                    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/gambar_soal/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
                    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                }else{
                    $config4['upload_path'] = './upload/gambar_opsi/';
                    $config4['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config4['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
                    $config4['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config4);
                }



                if($this->upload->do_upload($jenis[$i])) {
                    var_dump("hh");
                    $data1 = $this->upload->data();
                    $image_path = $data1['full_path'];
                    if(file_exists($image_path)) {
                        $status = "ok";
                        $msg = "Upload gambar berhasil";
                    } else {
                        $status = "ok";
                        $msg = "Terjadi kesalahan. Ulangi lagi.";
                    }
                    if($jenis[$i]=="gambar_soal"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT file FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET id_mapel = '".$this->input->post('id_mapel')."', 
                                        bobot_a ='" .$this->input->post('bobot_a'). "',
                                        bobot_b ='" .$this->input->post('bobot_b'). "',
                                        bobot_c ='" .$this->input->post('bobot_c'). "',
                                        bobot_d ='" .$this->input->post('bobot_d'). "',
                                        bobot_e='" .$this->input->post('bobot_e'). "',
                                        file = '".$data1['file_name']."', 
                                        soal = '".$this->input->post('soal')."'
                                        WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'");

                    @unlink("./upload/gambar_soal/".$ambil_gambar->file);
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_a"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT opsi_a FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_a = '".$data1['file_name']."#####".$data['opsi_a']."'
                                        WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");

                    @unlink("./upload/gambar_opsi/".$ambil_gambar->opsi_a);
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_b"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT opsi_b FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_b = '".$data1['file_name']."#####".$data['opsi_b']."'
                                            WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");

                        @unlink("./upload/gambar_opsi/".$ambil_gambar->opsi_b);

                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_c"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT opsi_c FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                                $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_c = '".$data1['file_name']."#####".$data['opsi_c']."'
                                                WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                            @unlink("./upload/gambar_opsi/".$ambil_gambar->opsi_c);
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_d"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT opsi_d FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                                    $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_d = '".$data1['file_name']."#####".$data['opsi_d']."'
                                                    WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");

                                @unlink("./upload/gambar_opsi/".$ambil_gambar->opsi_d);
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_e"){
                        $ambil_gambar = $this->db->query("SELECT opsi_e FROM m_soal WHERE id = '".$this->input->post('id')."'")->row();
                                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_e = '".$data1['file_name']."#####".$data['opsi_e']."'
                                                        WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");         
                                    @unlink("./upload/gambar_opsi/".$ambil_gambar->opsi_e);
                    }

                }else if (!$this->upload->do_upload($jenis[$i])) {
                    if($jenis[$i]=="gambar_soal"){
                    var_dump("hahah");
                    $status = 'ok';
                    $msg = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET id_mapel = '".$this->input->post('id_mapel')."', 
                                        bobot_a ='" . $data['bobot_a'] . "',
                                        bobot_b ='" . $data['bobot_b'] . "',
                                        bobot_c ='" . $data['bobot_c'] . "',
                                        bobot_d ='" . $data['bobot_d'] . "',
                                        bobot_e='" . $data['bobot_e'] . "',
                                        soal = '".$data['soal']."'

                                        WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_a"){
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_a = '".$data['foto_opsi_a']."#####".$data['opsi_a']."'
                    WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_b"){
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_b = '".$data['foto_opsi_b']."#####".$data['opsi_b']."'
                            WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");

                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_c"){
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_c = '".$data['foto_opsi_c']."#####".$data['opsi_c']."'
                            WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_d"){
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_d = '".$data['foto_opsi_d']."#####".$data['opsi_d']."'
                            WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                    }else if($jenis[$i]=="foto_opsi_e"){
                        $this->db->query("UPDATE m_soal SET opsi_e = '".$data['foto_opsi_e']."#####".$data['opsi_e']."'
                            WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
                    }

                } 
                //@unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
            }
        }


        redirect('adm/m_soal/');

        }


    }
```

Comment: What's the rest of your code? Where's the part that writes the file to disk?

Comment: sorry, I've updated my code

Comment: This code is unreadable. You're not going to get a lot of help if you can't format it nicely.

Comment: It's also got a lot of stuff that isn't relevant to your question, so you're making people do a lot of work just to figure out what's going on

Comment: I've updated my code, please kindly check it

Comment: Any more help here? I can help.